# Does .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 include 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

According to the [Microsoft download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25150):

> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 service pack 1 is a cumulative update
>   that contains many new features building incrementally upon .NET Framework
>   2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and includes .NET Framework 2.0 service pack 2 and .NET Framework 
>   3.0 service pack 2 cumulative updates.

so does .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 include 3.5 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is somewhat confusing but yes, as the title says, it's the "Full Package", so you get the original framework + the SP1 additions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The package contains both .NET 3.5 and the updates considered SP1. Looking at the size, it contains the entire .NET Framework from 2.0 upwards (which the CLR resides on that .NET 3.5 uses).

So this package should be sufficient when you want to use it or bundle it with a .NET 3.5 application to work on a system that doesn't have .NET installed yet, or just has .NET 1.1 (which will cause a side-by-side installation, since .NET 1.1 isn't compatible with .NET 2 and upwards).